# Ajax call to PHP success triggers error

Tags: php, ajax, email

I am calling a PHP function to send an email with information from a Form, the emails are being sent and received successfully and when I debug the PHP function it is returning TRUE. The problem is that the AJAX call is catching [object Object] error and it triggers the function in the error section in the AJAX call instead of the success one. Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Here is my Java Script code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#candidate_form").submit(function(){


$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "php/mail.php",
    data: { fname: $("#fname").val(), lname: $("#lname").val(), email: $("#email").val(), phone: $("#phone").val()},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response){
      alert(response)
      $("#jobModal").show();
    },
    error: function(response){
      alert("This action failed with the following error" + response);
    }
  })
  .done(function(data) {
    $("#jobModal").modal("show");
  })


});

</script>
```

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php


if (isset($_POST)) {
sendCandidate();
} 

function sendCandidate() {

 $emailTo="mail@gmail.com";
 $subject="Candidate Info Submited from Website";
 $body= "Hello!

A new candidate has submited his/her information from our website. Please check the candidate´s     information and contact him/her as soon as possible.

 Name: ". $_POST['fname']. " ". $_POST['lname']. 
 "
 Email: ".$_POST['email']. 
 "
 Phone: ". $_POST['phone'].
 "

Regards!

--
Jobs 
 ";
 $headers="From: candidates@jobs.com";

 #Sending mail with candidate´s info to recruiters.
 $candidateMailSent = mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);


 #Sending thank you email to candidate.
 mail($_POST['email'], "Jobs - Resume submited",
 "Hello ". $_POST['fname']." ". $_POST['lname']. ","."

We really appreciate your interest in working with us towards getting your new job. We have received your Resume and Contact Information and one of our Specialized Recruiters     will be getting in touch with you as soon as possible.

If you have any doubts please feel free to contact us by sending an email to     contact@jobs.com with the Subject: Candidate Inquiry.

Regards!

--
Jobs


 ", $headers);





 return json_encode($candidateMailSent);
}



?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you do a json_encode, it needs to be done on an array. Mail returns a boolean value which you are assigning to `$candidateMailSent`. You should probably assign this to `$candidateSentMail['success']`

in the php documentation for mail it says the return value is true or false. I didn't see that it returned a message.

Then on the jquery side you would test the response as responce.success

ex.,

```
   success: function(response.success){
      alert(response.success)
      $("#jobModal").show();
    },
    error: function(response.success){
      alert("This action failed with the following error" + response.success);
    }
```